# how to create alias of table name in Rails ActiveRecords

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
select user_id,  max(perception_score) as max, min(perception_score) as min from temp_user_notes group by user_id as t1;
```

I am trying to convert this sql query in rails active record but having a hard time to create aliases

Comment: Is the SQL query valid? Where is `t1` used?

Comment: yes it is valid actually its just a chunk of whole query just make it less complex. Whole query is      :

SELECT t2.user_id, t2.std_deviation FROM 
(SELECT t1.user_id, (t1.max - t1.min) as std_deviation FROM
(SELECT user_id,  MAX(perception_score) as max, MIN(perception_score) as min FROM temp_user_notes group by user_id) as t1) as t2
where t2.std_deviation > 30;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can alias the table to another name in the `from` method of ActiveRecord.

For example, part of your query could be:

```
TempUserNote.
  select("t1.user_id, (t1.max - t1.min) as std_deviation").
  from(
    TempUserNote.
      select("user_id, max(perception_score) as max, min(perception_score) as min").
      group(:user_id),
    :t1
  )
```

Comment: Finally something I went to himalayas looking for :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the SQL alias feature inside a `select` method call:

```
TempUserNote.select('user_id, max(perception_score) as max, min(perception_score) as min').group(:user_id)
```

Comment: But how will you use this in nested query like this:- 
SELECT t1.user_id, (t1.max - t1.min) as std_deviation FROM (SELECT user_id, MAX(perception_score) as max, MIN(perception_score) as min FROM temp_user_notes group by user_id) as t1) where t1.std_deviation > 30

Comment: @Lannister One question at a time, please. Did this solve your first problem?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler example:

```rb
Deliveries.from("deliveries deliveries_2")
```